# how to use gem generator carter rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, shopping-cart, activesupport

I'm trying to use the [carter gem](https://github.com/gillies-dunlop/carter) for my rails project. How do I use the gem to generate its pre-made controllers, views, and models?  There is no documentation for carter, so my attempt was to try `rails g carter` and `rails g carter:install`, both of which returned the following:

```
/home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': cannot load such file -- state_machine (LoadError)
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/carter-0.7.2/lib/carter/state_machine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/carter-0.7.2/lib/carter.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /home/hermes/coding/rails/seniorshub/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `require'
from /home/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

So two questions: Were my commands the correct ones, and if so, then how do I begin solving the above error (and what is the above error? Dependencies?) ?  If my commands were not correct, then what is the correct way of generating M's and V's and C's from a gem, specifically carter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is getting a bit off course, but you really don't want a gem that hasn't been touched in two years.

Consider the follwing instead:

- [Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree)
- [ror_ecommerce](https://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce)
- Paying for [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/)

Comment: I know, I didn't want to use carter either.  All I need is a shopping cart, no payments, no framework for a store - just want to add items from a list to a basket, with cart functionality.  Was looking for a simple gem.

Comment: I get it, but you don't have to use every feature in Spree, for example. Even if you solve this issue with Carter, another one will come up eventually. Fewer and fewer people will be able to help as this thing becomes more and more dead. I would say that trouble with installing counts as not simple haha.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!